# Fairly Secure for live site?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, security

I wanted to know if something like the following would be fairly secure and okay to use in a production setting.  I am retrieving data from a database and using the response data into a graph using Chart.js.

**My html file**

```
<div id="canvas-holder">
    <canvas id="chart-area2" width="200" height="200" />
</div>

<div id="canvas-holder">
    <canvas id="chart-area" width="200" height="200" />
</div>

<div id="chartjs-tooltip"></div>


<script>
$.ajax({
   url: 'chartpi.php',
   success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php 
        var datachart = JSON.parse(response);
        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(datachart);
   }
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'chartpi2.php',
   success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php
        var datachart = JSON.parse(response);
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
        window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(datachart);
   }
});
</script>
```

**My PHP file**

```
<?php

        // set up the connection variables
        $db_name  = '$dbname';
        $hostname = '$host';
        $username = '$uname';
        $password = '$pass';

        // connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

        // a query get all the records from the users table
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM pichart2';

        // use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good practice
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // fetch the results into an array
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

        // convert to json
        $json = json_encode( $result );

        // echo the json string
        echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: At a glance, this looks reasonably secure.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I am still new to php security so I am a little confused as to where code can be improved to be more secure.

Comment: Make sure that you are using SSL for the requests

Comment: your main concern is with user input but this has none

Comment: @Ben that's not needed for no user input

Comment: it is if the data he is getting back is sensitive

Comment: One thing: you have two `<div>` tags with the same id of `canvas-holder`. This makes it impossible to differentiate between them. Other than that, looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question of

> *would be fairly secure and okay to use in a production setting*

The two obvious area's you have covered

- parameterized queries on the backend
- the data being retrieved is not based on user input from **this** site page

However, I will caution that if any of the data being retrieved from the piechart table(s) retains any user provided data from some other source, that you should consider/implement the proper [output encoding](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Output_Encoding_Rules_Summary) **even** if proper input sanitation was performed.

If that isn't the case, then no worry there.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I will look more into the encoding for future use, when I decide to add user input into the charts.